# What are the ways to save TableEntity with an Image as property?

Tags: c#, azure

Pretty objective question here but am considering what could be used.

Task is to save an object with an image as part of its properties. The object will be saved as a TableEntity in Azure and image could be in a blob (with the url as the property value in tablestorage). But am open to suggestions.

Am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803362.aspx) right now and still welcome to suggestions.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The object will be saved as a TableEntity in Azure and image could be
>   in a blob (with the url as the property value in tablestorage)

I believe this is the right approach as blob storage is right place for storing unstructured data.

You could also save the image contents in table storage by storing image data as `Binary` data type or converting image data into Base64 format string, but I would recommend going against it. Here're are my reasons:

- Maximum size of each attribute in an entity can be 64K thus you're limited to smaller images only.
- Assuming the images you're dealing with are small, you still incur an overhead of serialization/deserialization when writing/reading image to/from table storage.